# Unassigned local variable and converting char to string

Tags: c#, .net

Making a program that converts Alphanumeric phone numbers to a regular phone number (ex.123-TRAVELS = 123-872-8357), but trying to figure some (probably simple to fix) errors to display the results under the CheckButton_Click variable. I'm giving myself a headache right now trying to figure this out. These are the current errors for the pasted code:
[image]

```
public static string PhoneToNumber(string str)
    {
        // Array version of value
        var phoneNumberArr = str.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            phoneNumberArr[i] = PhoneCharToNumber(phoneNumberArr[i]);
        }
        return new string(phoneNumberArr);
    }

    public static char PhoneCharToNumber(char value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'C':
                return '2';
            case 'D':
            case 'E':
            case 'F':
                return '3';
            case 'G':
            case 'H':
            case 'I':
                return '4';
            case 'J':
            case 'K':
            case 'L':
                return '5';
            case 'M':
            case 'N':
            case 'O':
                return '6';
            case 'P':
            case 'Q':
            case 'R':
                return '7';
            case 'S':
            case 'T':
            case 'U':
                return '8';
            case 'V':
            case 'W':
            case 'X':
            case 'Y':
            case 'Z':
                return '9';
            default: return value;

        }
    }

private void CheckButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string str = inputTextBox.Text;
        char value = PhoneCharToNumber(value);
        resultsLabel.Text = value;

    }

    private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Closes the form
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you wanted to do `string value = PhoneToNumber(str);` inside `CheckButton_Click`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here: `char value = PhoneCharToNumber(value);`
where `value` argument for `PhoneCharToNumber` hasn't been declared nor assigned.

I think you wanted to use string `value = PhoneToNumber(str);` instead.
Infact your user enters number inside `inputTextBox`; you have to convert that text to a valid number and then place the result to `resultsLabel`.

```
private void CheckButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = inputTextBox.Text;
    string value = PhoneToNumber(str);
    resultsLabel.Text = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the CheckButton_Click method, you pass value as parameter. Value is undefined at that moment, you should pass str (which is a bad name) like this. Beside that PhoneCharToNumber returns a string not a char:

```
private void CheckButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string textToProcess = inputTextBox.Text;
    string processedText = PhoneToNumber(textToCheck );
    resultsLabel.Text = processedText ;

}
```